# SQL_NO_CACHE with Laravel query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to add `SQL_NO_CACHE` command into query made with Laravel query builder, but always get error because query builder treat `SQL_NO_CACHE` as column name. 
I tried raw methods like `selectRaw` and `select(\DB::raw())`.

Is there alternative way to use SQL_NO_CACHE with query builder.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same, but this will prevent from getting cached results also:

```
$query->addSelect(DB::raw('now()'));
```